# Codeigniter route not work with parameters

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have controller `Post` with methods `index`, `add` and `delete`. I create routes rule for this actions:

```
$route['posts'] = 'post/index'; // <-- Work 
$route['post-add'] = 'post/add';// <-- Work 
$route['post-delete/(:num)'] = 'post/delete/$1'; // <-- Not Work
```

First route `www.example.com/posts` work good, and second with `/post-add` work. But when i call `post-delete/5` that not work, all time i get `404 Not Fount`.

**Here is controller**

```
class Post extends MY_Controller
{
     public function index()
     { 
         //.
     }

     public function add()
     { 
         //.
     }

     public function delete($id)
     { 
         echo "Delete post #ID =" $id;
     }
}
```

I have only problem with `delete` route i dont know whay he dont accept that parameter.

**Work:**

- www.example.com/posts
- www.example.com/add

**Not work:**

- www.example.com/delete/1

What can be problem?

Comment: may be u forget to add `$this->load->helper('url');` in ur controller

Comment: Try with `$route['post/delete/(:num)']`

Comment: @Maninderpreet Singh `url` is autoloaded in config.

Comment: @Saty when i try your example i get the some `Not Found

The requested URL /post/delete/1 was not found on this server.`

Comment: Can you add whole routes.php file here? I have an idea but should see routes.php completely first.

Comment: That is all what i have inside `routes.php`. Also i have `$route['default_controller'] = 'wall/index';` and nothing else

Comment: Add this line under default_controller: `$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;`

Comment: `post/delete/$1` should work without routes rewrite. Make it work first without any changes in `routes.php`.

Comment: I think that you have a problem with the method "public function delete()"

Comment: What CI version is that?

Comment: You can use `post/delete/$1` without any changes (like @Tpojka said), but if you really want to reroute it, you should check the `www.example.com/post-delete/1` link in your environment.

Answer (score -1):

Add it to route file

```
$route['delete/(:num)'] = 'post/delete/$1'
```